# Why does std::future::wait_for not behave as expected?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, time, future

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>

using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    std::promise<void> prom;
    auto               fut = prom.get_future();

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (
         std::future_status::timeout ==
         fut.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds::max())
    );
}
```

The code should output nothing, because `fut.wait_for` will wait for a very very long time. However, it outputs `true` in no time!

**Why does `std::future::wait_for` not behave as expected?**

Comment: This is possibly due to overflow in the relative time calculation (`system_clock::now() + chrono::seconds::max()`).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I think that's exactly what it is, the g++ implementation converts to absolute time just like your snippet.

Comment: I debugged the g++ implementation and that's what it is. I can't determine from the standard whether that's permitted, or not, despite all "wait_for"s on cppreference.com describe them as such.

Comment: I can't see anything in the standard that gives permission for this to not work. File a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to overflow with the relative time calculation resulting in Undefined Behavior.

There's nothing I've found in the standard that specifically addresses overflow with `wait_for`, so we need to rely on the standard handling of overflow, which depends on the underlying types involved.

[`std::chrono::seconds`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) is typedef for [`std::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), using a type that is a *signed integral type of at least 35 bits*.  Adding two duration values involves adding two signed integers.  It is Undefined Behavior when [signed integer addition overflows](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).

Therefore, the behavior is undefined when waiting for a really long time.

Comment: "std::chrono::seconds is typedef for std::ratio<1>. " No. And the type of the template parameters of `ratio` has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: @T.C. I basing my wording for what  was in the cppreference page I linked to.  Checking the standard, in [time.syn] it has a section commented "// convenience typedefs" which includes `using seconds = duration<signed integer type of at least 35 bits >;`.  This is an _alias-declaration_, which introduces a  _typedef-name_ (see [dcl.typedef]).  The type of the template parameters for `ratio` is the type that is stored internally and the type which is used when doing operations like addition.

Comment: I think you are mixing up `duration` and `ratio`.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for pointing that out.  I misread what was stated, paying more attention to the links than the preceding text.  I've (hopefully) corrected the answer.